# DrawableTint not workoing with AppCompatButton on API 23

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-appcompat

I am using an AppCompatButton (Version: *androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha01*) with a drawable. It works fine but not with API 23. The drawableTint attribute should work in API 23 but it does not do anything. With higher APIs it works fine and even when I change the API in the Design Editor of Android Studio down to 23, the color is correct. But not on a emulator with API 23. Can you help me? Thanks in advance[image: ButtonComparison]

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/loginWithGoogle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_loginbutton_google_statelist"
                android:backgroundTint="@null"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_google"
                android:drawableTint="@color/NavbarAccent"
                android:text="@string/google"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/NavbarAccent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginOrConnectUsing"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `app:drawableTint` if you want the AppCompat application of tint that works on all API levels.